# httpd always keep start itself, the cpu load is very high

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

My dedicated server has a problem after i reboot itself.
The cpu load average is very high as following detail after i run top command

```
top - 23:40:41 up 50 min,  3 users,  load average: 236.24, 146.96, 124.29
Tasks: 556 total,   1 running, 555 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.2%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 98.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16230212k total,  2994040k used, 13236172k free,    26404k buffers
Swap:  2097144k total,        0k used,  2097144k free,
```

i tried to stop httpd, it show 'OK' but after i run "service httpd status" it still show it's running.

there are many process related to httpd after i run "ps -ef | grep httpd"

```
 apache    7984  7209  0 23:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 apache    7985  7209  0 23:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k s
```

I have no idea what it is but it keep duplicate itself every second (the pid run very fast)

after i dig into the unix log (var/log/message)
it show some log which may related to harddisk, i'm not quite sure, is it?

```
Nov 10 00:16:13 host kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Nov 10 00:16:13 host kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Nov 10 00:16:13 host kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Nov 10 00:16:13 host kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:f0:e1:4a/00:00:6b:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
Nov 10 00:16:13 host kernel:         res 41/40:08:f0:e1:4a/00:00:6b:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Nov 10 00:16:13 host kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Nov 10 00:16:13 host kernel: ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Nov 10 00:16:13 host kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov 10 00:16:13 host kernel: ata1: EH complete
```

Please advice me how should i do next to have my server become normal again.

Best Regards,

Comment: after i dig into the unix log (var/log/message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're running Red Hat (Because of 'HTTPD'). It looks like your hard drive is failing. I suggest you install and run SMART on your drive(s) to confirm.

```
yum install smartmontools
```

And then for example to check your first drive

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

This will output a whole boatload of information, you will want to pay attention near the bottom where you may see something like

```
Error 6 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2263 hours (94 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 71 04 81 87 80 e0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT
```

This means your drive is failing and you should backup and replace the drive ASAP. If you post the output we can have a more detailed look.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive has failed. Replace the defective hard drive.